# rails bootstrap modal partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Using Rails 4.2.6, Bootstrap-saas 3.2.0
I have a collection of products which i'm rendering in my index view like this. Using bootstrap gridsystem

```
.row
  =render partial: 'product', collection: @products
```

The product partial

```
   .col-sm-6.col-md-4
    .thumbnail
    %h2 My Box
    %ul
      %li=product.name
      %li=product.brand
      %li=product.model
      %li="$#{product_price(product.price)}"
      =link_to 'more info', '#dialog', 'data-toggle' => 'modal'
```

I want to display a modal for each rendered product with product.description,product.name displayed in the modal. The problem I'm having is, the modal is only loading with the first product information only. It's supposed to show product information for each product. my modal html markup

```
    #dialog.modal.fade{'aria-hidden' => 'true', 'aria-labelledby' =>         'myModalLabel', 'data-backdrop' => 'static', 'data-keyboard' => 'true', :role => 'dialog', :tabindex => '-1'}
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %button.close{'aria-label' => 'Close', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal', :type => 'button'}
          %span{'aria-hidden' => 'true'} &times;
        %h3.modal-title=product.name
      .modal-body
        %h2=product.desc
      .modal-footer
        =button_tag 'close', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal'
```

Comment: What javascript are you using to initialize your modals?

Comment: $('#myModal').modal('toggle')

Comment: Are you sure? It seems like you don't have any `#myModal` code in your haml file.

Comment: sorry, i'm using #dialog instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a CSS `id` for your modal with `'#dialog'` selector. Your CSS `id`s must be unique on your page.

So, you would have to add a unique identifier for your modal boxes. For example adding a `product.id` to its `id`:

```
=link_to 'more info', "#dialog-#{product.id}", 'data-toggle' => 'modal'
```

and in your modal partial:

```
.modal.fade{id="dialog-#{product.id}", 'aria-hidden' => 'true', 'aria-labelledby' => 'myModalLabel', 'data-backdrop' => 'static', 'data-keyboard' => 'true', :role => 'dialog', :tabindex => '-1'}
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      -# etc.
```

Comment: BTW, you could have used `dom_id(product)` helper to generate unique `id`s for your models. The syntax in example above is for clarity of what needs to be done.